# How am I supposed to know what order to hit the generators for this riddle?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In Panessa Studios, there's a room with generators that holds one of Riddler's riddle.

[image: riddle room]

To get the riddle, the generators needed to be hit in a particular order.  As far as I know, there weren't any hints to the order that should have been taken.  Detective mode didn't reveal anything.  I couldn't see any obvious hints in the posters.  After a number of random guesses, I was eventually able to get it.

> Starting from the left: 1 5 7 3 2 4 8 6

**How was I supposed to know in what order to hit the generators?**

Comment: off topic: What is your rig? The game lags on Titan X!

Comment: I have TItan Blacks in SLI but am running the game in single GPU mode.  It's fairly stable but as usual, will eventually crash.  It crashes much sooner when in SLI.

Comment: WB announced that they are working on a fix and they showed their dedication by taking it off sale. (and I bought deluxe edition for a cheap price thanks to that move) I hope that they'll fix it soon, as I hope to play it.

Comment: If it's any help, @ardaozkal, I'm running at mostly 50-60fps on an R9 290, though this is without gameworks, and with 32GB of RAM, running on SSD etc.

Comment: @Jeeva I have GT820 on my laptop and an old AMD on my old desktop. I never needed more power tho. These cards provide 60fps for me. Except on this damn game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it goes by the age of the person on the poster (starting at the youngest, from baby to grave, if you can consider "grave" an age haha).

Comment: That sounds about right. I've left the area by now but I think the posters were like that.

Comment: Aha! I ended up solving it by trial and error. Never did work out a pattern. I hoped somebody would ask and answer this. :)

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't until after I solved it through trial and error did I recognize that the posters revealed the life span and that was the clue. During the initial process, it was baffling and I couldn't identify a single clue.